# Relaciones de tablas

Tags: mysql, sql

Saludos a esta gran comunidad, espero que mi pregunta ayuda a las personas que tienen la misma duda y a la vez, ser ayudado.

Bueno me encuentro con este dilema al diseñar una base de datos:

Al agregar un equipo a mi bd como obtendría el país al que pertenecen, lo que estado pensando es agregarle también el atributo idpais, pero no se si es correcto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas agregar una columna `idPais`, porque sabiendo la ciudad, ya con eso puedes obtener el país.

La consulta sería:

```
SELECT 
    co.nameCountry 
FROM tbteam AS te 
    INNER JOIN tbcity AS ci ON te.idCity=ci.idCity
    INNER JOIN tbcountry AS co ON ci.idCountry=co.idCountry
```

Comment: ante todo gracias por la respuesta, entonces lo mas correcto es agregar a mi tabla ciudad desde el código 0 hasta el código n ciudades que hay en el mundo? ya que estaba pensando reiniciar a 0 el codCiudad por cada pais.

Comment: @Renzo_vzn no necesariamente. Las ciudades las agregas según los equipos. ¿En tu sistema hay equipos de las ciudades de todo el mundo?  ¿O hay equipo de 50 ciudades? Entonces agregas solamente esas 50 ciudades, pero agrega también el país de cada una de ellas. No puedes tener miles o millones de ciudades si no las vas a usar todas.

Comment: comprendo el punto, pero esta consulta solo funcionaria si mi idciudad 1 no este contenida en otro país, ya que me devolvería dos países. Por lo que te comento que lo mas correcto seria agregar cada ciudad con ids diferentes.Es posible que necesite agregar todas las ciudades para poder listar un combobox de dos niveles.

Comment: @Renzo_vzn en `tbcity` tendrías que agregar una restricción `UNIQUE` usando las columnas `(nameCity, idCountry)` porque puede haber dos ciudades con el mismo nombre, pero no en el mismo país... no al menos para el caso de los equipos porque en la vida real sí sería posible, y en ese caso la restricción sería con (`nameCity, idState`), un identificador más específico, que sería el estado o provincia...

Answer (score 0):

Pues según la 4 forma normal el `Equipo` hacia el `Pais` y `Ciudad` es una referencia múltiple donde `Equipo` no es dependiente para crear `Paises o Ciudades` entonces deberías crear una tabla `pais_equipo` o `ciudad_equipo` y hacer la relación de esa forma.

> Llegar a la 3 Forma Normal se puede decir que estas "Bien", pero si deseas ser mas estricto crea la tabla de relación que hace falta

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta,por el momento no comprendo muy bien la  4ta y 5ta forma normal.